# Wrapping text in curved shape arround an image

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I want to wrap text in oval shape arround an image but the text keep overlapping over the image. I tried changind the `border-radius`, `width` and `height` properties etc. of the wraping element (i.e image)  but it doesn't work. Below is my html and css code:

**Html:**

```
<div id="circular-shape">
<img src="blackberries-basket.jpg" class="curve">
<p>/*...text to wrap around circle side...*/ 
</p> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#circular-shape { 
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; 
  margin: 2rem; 
}
#circular-shape p { 
  line-height: 1.8; 
}

#circular-shape .curve { 
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  min-width: 250px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-shape-outside:circle();
  shape-outside:circle();
}
```

How can I stop the text from touching/overlapping the image at the left.Please help.

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/css-shapes-101

Comment: https://www.html5andbeyond.com/wrap-text-around-a-rounded-image-using-css-shape-outline/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

Comment: thanks for these informative links :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just add margin:

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin: .5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50%);
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/100/100" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate ipsam harum enim omnis, iure laboriosam perferendis neque minima aspernatur culpa recusandae sunt quae minus, est quo ipsum ipsa laborum aperiam itaque facere sequi similique dignissimos
    repellendus excepturi! Doloribus, voluptate! Voluptatibus facere nisi nesciunt aliquid maxime vitae soluta earum sint quis distinctio, molestias quod dicta deleniti debitis accusantium at fugiat illum voluptatum dignissimos dolore temporibus obcaecati
    sunt non. Amet, et? Consequatur iusto nihil blanditiis amet placeat deleniti perspiciatis odit esse officia, dolor molestiae illum quo maiores quia nam delectus ut libero temporibus eveniet aperiam, nemo cupiditate, similique porro reprehenderit.
    Molestiae, perspiciatis!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS

```
p {
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
}
```

Increase the pixels if you want to.